# Excel formula slows down Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have been applying this formula in my Excel spreadsheet but when I enter this formula in multiple cells, my Excel calculating processor slows down and eventually crashes. Is there any way to make this formula work faster?

**Purpose of formula: To count filtered data with 2 conditions (Y being positive and subject name being X) applied within the formula.**

Multiple cells as what I mean is that Dryness + absorbency is one of the fields. There are about few fields for different brands ( Brand A , Brand B , Brand C)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
--(INDEX('Current Month'!$A:BJ,0,MATCH("Subject Name",'Current Month'!$A$1:$BJ$1,0))="Pampers"),
--(INDEX('Current Month'!$A:BJ,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current Month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0))="POSITIVE"),
--(IF(SUBTOTAL(103,INDIRECT("'Current Month'!$A"&ROW(A:A)&":$A"&ROW(A:A))),1,0)=1)
)
```

Hope someone can help as I have tried multiple times and my Excel keeps crashing. Thank you.

Comment: you could cut down the full column references and change the volatile indirect to a non-volatile index. sample data with expected results needed to assist further.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I have added the dummy file in the question. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you replace the `INDIRECT` with `INDEX`?  Indirect has a big overhead because they are recalculated every time recalculation is triggered - even if they don't need to be.

Comment: I've done some speed testing and I am approaching an answer but I am still unclear on why you use the column BJ and AJ in the same function. Also why is column A absolute (e.g. $A) and column AJ/BJ is relative (AJ/BJ can be filled right for AK/BK, etc). I'm also unclear why you would post 'sample data' complete with (limited) narrative that does not correspond with your question's narrative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict the array in your formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('Current Month'!A1:A32,ROW('Current Month'!A1:A32)-MIN(ROW('Current Month'!A1:A32)),,1))*--(INDEX('Current Month'!$A1:BJ32,0,MATCH("Subject Name",'Current Month'!$A$1:$BJ$1,0))="Pampers")*--(INDEX('Current Month'!$A1:BJ32,0,MATCH("Dryness + Absorbency",'Current Month'!$A$1:$AJ$1,0))="POSITIVE"))
```

Comment: Hi,

   Thanks for the reply. The column letter is not fixed, it is different for each dataset thus i want it to find for the column header name and use the column. The formula you provided has like specified column letters for eg. D1:D32 = POSITIVE

Comment: @Faheera Edited the formula to substitute the dynamic columns.

Answer (score 1):

The reason excel is crashing is because:

```
INDEX('Current Month'!$A:BJ
```

That would be an array of over 65 million cells.

Name your array, only the rows needed, and use that instead of `'Current Month'!$A:BJ`.  I didn't examine the rest of your formula, but this is where I would start.  Same goes for the rest of your arrays.